# Prove the integration is convergent

Tags: integration

$$\int^{+\infty}_{0} \frac{ |\sin x| }{x(1+ \sqrt x)} dx$$

I try to set a upper boundary 1 for $| \sin x |$, but it doesn't work well

This is initially to prove the absolute convergence

Comment: Try using $|\sin(x)| \leq x$ for $x < 1$ and $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$ for $x > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your observation that $|\sin x| \le 1$ for all $x$ together with the fact that

$$1 + \sqrt x > \sqrt x$$

we have

$$\frac{|\sin x|}{x(1 + \sqrt x)} \le \frac{1}{x \sqrt x} = x^{-3/2}$$

Now it's easy to check that $\int_1^{\infty} x^{-3/2} dx$ is convergent, dealing with the integral on $[1,\infty)$.

---

On the other hand, we have that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

implying (as a rather weak corollary) that $\sin x / x$ remains bounded near the origin. Hence the integrand is bounded on $(0,1]$, and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ |\sin x| }{x(1+ \sqrt x)}=1$ since $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

Since the function is positive, you need to prove that the integral is above bounded
So try considering the function equal to 1 on [0,1] and equal to $\frac{1}{x\sqrt x}$ on $]1,\infty[$